# Single quote in JSON field POSTGRESQL

Tags: json, postgresql, escaping, single-quotes

I am trying to manipulate a JSON with a single quote inside, and I am having some troubles:

1.- When I have a function, I cant pass as parameter a JSON string with a single quote inside: 
This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.give_me_text
(
  IN  text  json
)
RETURNS JSON AS
$$
DECLARE
v_text   varchar;
begin

RAISE NOTICE 'text: %', text;
v_text:=text || '- hello';
return v_text;
end
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

By calling like this is working:

```
SELECT * FROM give_me_text
(
'{"es":"name 1","en":"name 2","de":"name 3","fr":"name 4","pt":"name 5"}'
);
```

But when I have got a single quote is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM give_me_text
    (
    '{"es":"nam'e 1","en":"name 2","de":"name 3","fr":"name 4","pt":"name 5"}'
    );
```

2.- When I am tryhing to insert JSON value with Single quote inside, it is giving me the same error:
This is working:

```
INSERT INTO public.my_columns VALUES ('{ "name": "Book the First", "author": { "first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "White" } }');
```

But this is not working:

```
INSERT INTO public.my_columns VALUES ('{ "name": "Book's the First", "author": { "first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "White" } }');
```

Any ideas how to escape this single quote? Thanks

Comment: Just make it a double single quote `''`

Comment: I have tried with REPLACE but always is giving me an error. I must put it by code because this string is from database, sometimes is coming with single quotes and sometimes not.

Answer (score 20):

In SQL, single quote must be escaped in a string.  This is not a valid string:

```
'{"es":"nam'e 1"}'
```

because the string ends after `"nam`.  You can escape the single quote by repeating it:

```
'{"es":"nam''e 1"}'
```

If you're doing [dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), you can pass parameters to `execute`:

```
execute 'insert into YourTable (col1) values ($1);' using json_var;
```

Comment: But your string is not valid SQL. It has to come from somewhere?

Comment: yes, it is a valid json string. It is coming from a json field. I loop with a cursor all the records,then i make a SELECT dinamycally and I concatenate this value, and then I have no valid string